# Why is Network Render creating .exr's instead of .png's?

Tags: python, rendering, .exr

So i have been fighting this 2 days now. As i send job to slave computer on Network render and have told it to use cycles engine, where i have set the default output type to png, it still returns rendered images as .exr files... Would not be problem on still images, but at VSE i'd like to use png as .exr doesn't seem to work on it too well (need to use composite to even see the frames)

So what py. file i need to modify to change deafault network render output to .png and do i have to modify it on master + client computer or in a slave computer?

Edit: Some screenies. Like you can see; master, client and slave settings are not tweaked. Only changed Client engine setting to cycles
[image: Client and master settings]

[image: Slave settings]

[image: Cycles render settings]

Comment: That's a good question... Can you upload some screenshots of your settings?

Comment: Settings should be fine, but i'm pretty sure it's related to python scripts. Too bad i haven't started to learning python yet, to track the bit of code that makes this happen.

Comment: In your question, you originally called it the "Network Render addon." Which addon are you using?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T25034):

> "the problem is that even if you have PNG selected in the blend to be
>   rendered, if you use the 'Download render results from Network', they
>   will always come back as layered .exr files. You only get them as PNGs
>   when you press 'get animation' button."

Have you tried the Get Animation button instead?

Or, according to [this page](https://www.quora.com/Good-software-for-network-rendering-Which-one):

> If you just need PNG then in the network render properties, under
>   client tab you should choose 'animation on network' rather than 'send
>   job to network'. Both will render in EXR file but with 'animation on
>   network' option, it'll deliver the png (or whatever format you choose)
>   to specified folder.

I would say, if you set your Render output folder path to "//something", which means relative to the blend file, with the output type as PNG, and then initiated the job by choosing Animation on Network, and then when complete, retrieve the frames with the Get Animation button, it should bring back PNG files.

Comment: Yes i have tried that also, for animation and that brought me 70 .exr files instead of png

Comment: Ok, found additional info, please review.

Comment: Sorry but i thought i found them first, but they were my earlier renders on normal cycles... Any idea what that spesific folder could be as it aint, folder set on network render settings, nor it doesn't sent those png's to cycles output folder either